# כי הלא בזולת בשר כבדת את השבת

Tags: shabbat, eating, meat, acharonim

The full text is:

מה שהלכת אתמול לבקש בשר ואבדת חצי היום ולא יכולת למצוא ואף תרנגולים שבאו לידך לא אסתייעא מלתא הכל מאתי היה להודיעך שהבשר והיין שהם משכן היצה"ר אין לרדוף אחריהם **כי בזולתם יחיה האדם כי הלא בזולת בשר כבדת את השבת**.

and it comes from Rav Karo in מגיד משרים.

Can someone explain what is being said about meat on Shabbat?

I understand so far: " . . . the wine and meat are the home of the Yetser Ha-Ra and one should not chase them because without them man can live and ________ you honored Shabbat."

The blank I think should be something like "without meat you honored Shabbat," but I am not sure since it seems to contradict whatRav Karo says in Shulhan Aruch.

Comment: Hai welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 
Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: Note that not all is Shulchan Aruch, despite the name of the author.

Comment: @Haim if you are the same user as Hai, you can ask for your IDs to be combined

Comment: @Haim / hai thanks for the expansion! You could make the question even more compelling by citing/quoting what you're alluding to at the end in the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: בזולת בשר כבדת את השבת = without meat you honored the Sabbath

Answer (score 1):

"Isn't the case that you have honored the shabat **with something else than** meat?!" or "even with other things". As if the said him "You know that you have successfully / I want to tell you that you have successfully ..."

He do not ruled that there is no need for meat. In this case, the Shabbat was without meat because of lack of meat at this time. The reproach is about spending a too length amount of time for Shabbat's meat (with the intent of honoring shabbat), it was exaggerated. And this what the failure shows. The maggid explains that the message was that to spend many hours for meat, even for Mitsva, is least important than studying Torah. He explain Rabbi Yosef Karo nevertheless managed to honor the Shabbat.

Answer (score 0):

> *And behold, you have honored the Sabbath absent any meat.*

(*Zulat* meaning "none" or "other.")

The mystical being in *Magid Mesharim* also advises those on a high spiritual level to avoid eating meat on Rosh Hashana, so it wouldn't surprise me if it also says there's no need for it on Shabbat.

(What to make of *Magid Mesharim* ... and how Rabbi Karo considered it or didn't when codifying halacha ... are broader questions. In short -- I wouldn't sweat it too much.)

Comment: Thanks Shalom, I read that *Magid Mesharim* came out years after *Shulhan Arukh*, which explains why he didn't consider it. In any event, I don't eat meat, so not particularly worried.

Comment: כי הלא does not mean "and behold".